# Use a (virtual) hard drive in windows docker image

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to create a base docker image for a windows application. I know that windows images have their drawbacks and their pitfalls but the application won't run in a linux environment.
It is necessary to have some data on the G: drive and that is where I can't seem to get it to work. I don't need to map the G: volume to my hard drive, I just need to install some stuff there. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2

Volume "G:"

RUN powershell wget http://some.url/file.zip -OutFile G:\file.zip
RUN tar -xf G:\file.zip -C G:
```

But the docker build fails on the last line because the file does not show up on the G: drive. I tried downloading the file to the C: drive and then extract it to G: and I also tried to extract it to C: and then copy it to G: but none have worked. The G: drive is always empty.
When I exec into the container and run the commands from the Dockerfile it works as expected. Only when I run `docker build` the G: drive is completely ignored.
What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The virtual G: drive is created in the intermediate container and is reset with every RUN stage.
What I did instead is to create a directory C:\g_drive within the container and mounted it to G:

```
RUN mkdir C:\g_drive

RUN powershell Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices' -Name 'G:' -Value "\??\c:\g_drive"
```